# Migration from hydro to kinetic

Tags: ros, driver, ros-kinetic, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to find a kinetic kame driver for a motor controller (Roboteq AX2550) but the closest thing I found was a driver from hydro ( https://github.com/wjwwood/ax2550 ). After copying it from github, I can't figure out how to convert it over to kinetic kame.

In CMakeLists.txt, I changed

**find_package(catkin REQUIRED
COMPONENTS
geometry_msgs
nav_msgs
roscpp
serial
serial_utils
tf
)**

to

**find_package(catkin REQUIRED NO_MODULE)**

as per instructions on http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Migration

but then it says

*"If you were using the exported dependency list to pass a CMake module name that will not work anymore. **You will need to find the CMake module manually in your CMake extra file.** "*

I have no idea what this means. How do I find those CMake modules manually? What/where is that CMake extra file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252596/migration-from-hydro-to-kinetic/) by [Auton0mous](https://answers.ros.org/users/29134/auton0mous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was going about it all wrong, I didn't have to modify anything

I deleted the directory with the kinetic driver and re-copied the github directory. Then I added a few other directories from github into my catkin_ws/src folder.

- common_msgs
- serial
- serial_utils

and now it passes catkin_make

---

Originally posted by [Auton0mous](https://answers.ros.org/users/29134/auton0mous/) with karma: 38 on 2017-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1